# How to set player move ability when overlaping the ladder

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I’m writing a simple platformer game. I use tiled maps to create level layers for overlaps and collisions. I’m stuck with a problem: I’m trying to make player be able to climb the ladder when overlap with ladder tile happens.

I have a variable in gameSettings object playerMoveY: false (so by default player can only walk left or right)

When player overlaps the ladder tile he's able to climb but after that he's always able to climb because variable playerMoveY is still = true. I don't know how to switch it back. Maybe using the flag is not a good idea. I need advice. Thank you.

```
let gameSettings = {
    playerSpeed: 60,
    playerMoveY: false,
}

//here's the code from gameScene class
this.laddersLayer.setTileIndexCallback(29, this.allowClimb, this);
this.physics.add.overlap(this.player, this.laddersLayer);

    movePlayerManager() {
        if (this.cursorKeys.left.isDown) {
            this.player.anims.play('playerWalkLeft', true);
            this.player.setVelocityX(-gameSettings.playerSpeed);
        } else if (this.cursorKeys.right.isDown) {
            this.player.anims.play('playerWalkRight', true);
            this.player.setVelocityX(gameSettings.playerSpeed);
        } else {
            this.player.setVelocityX(0);
            this.player.anims.play('playerStand');
        }

        if (gameSettings.playerMoveY) {

        if (this.cursorKeys.up.isDown) {
                this.player.anims.play('playerClimb', true);
                this.player.setVelocityY(-gameSettings.playerSpeed);
            } else if (this.cursorKeys.down.isDown) {
                this.player.anims.play('playerClimb', true);
                this.player.setVelocityY(gameSettings.playerSpeed);
            } else {
                this.player.setVelocityY(0);
            }
        }
    }

//and here's the callback function when overlap
    allowClimb() {
        gameSettings.playerMoveY = true;
    }
```

Comment: You need a different way of detecting ladder tiles because using the current one, you'd have to set a TileIndexCallback for all other tiles, too, one that resets `gameSettings.playerMoveY` to `false` for all tiles except ladder ones.

Answer (score 0):

You currently only check if the player is overlapping the ladder, and subsequently setting:`gameSettings.playerMoveY = true;`. You need a check for other types of tiles. I've never used tiled so I don't know how it works but I would suggest trying to implement something like this in the update function:

```
//this is just sudo code
if(player.byLadder() == true){
    player.canClimb = true;
}else{
    player.canClimb = false;
}
```

The player.byLadder() function would somehow have to return true at all times the player can climb (before climbing, while climbing, at the end of the climb). Again, I apologize for not having more concrete code as I've never touched Tiled.